# How to find which changelists will be copied?

Tags: perforce

I want to be able to do a 'p4 describe' on all the changelists that will be copied upon a 'p4 copy' command. How can this be done?

I could do something like:

```
p4 copy -n from-branch/... to-branch/... | sed -e 's|.* ||' | xargs -n 1 p4 filelog
```

to find the list of changes per file and truncate the list at the point of the last branch or integrate action into to-branch (if there is one). But this could potentially take a long time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`p4 interchanges`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/interchanges.html). I like the `-l` and `-f` flags, which print the whole changelist description and list the files changed:

```
p4 interchanges -lf from-branch/... to-branch/...
```

I haven't actually used this command with `p4 copy`, though, so the results might be slightly different. If you're doing especially fancy integrations (cherry-picking revisions) Perforce might show a changelist as needing to be integrated even when it's already been integrated.

Comment: Yes, 'p4 copy' is a bit different from 'integrate'.  It will try to make the two codelines converge, so if you had merged and ignored a changelist, it'll be a candidate for copy.

Comment: @p4-randall, the to-branch is a long-lived release branch. I tried 'p4 interchanges' and it looks like it works for what I want to do. Do you see any corner cases in which it might not?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to create a label and tag from-branch/... at the last CL that was copied to to-branch from from-branch. Then finding out the list of CLs not copied is as easy as:

```
p4 changes 'from-branch/...@>copied-up-to' # where copied-up-to is the name of the dynamic label
```

If everything under from-branch is all tagged at the same CL, I could use a dynamic label whose Revision spec would be the last CL that was copied to to-branch from from-branch.

Answer (score 0):

A script is probably the right way to go.  I'd use the perl, python, or ruby API to make it more efficient and easier to maintain.

The basic outline would be:

- Run `p4 copy -n` to get the list of candidate files
- Parse out the source revisions that are being copied.  For instance, each line of output has something like "branch/sync from //depot/foo.c#1,#3".  For that file you'd want to know how revisions 1-3 were created.
- Run `p4 changes` to get the changelists that affected each file (e.g. `p4 changes -l //depot/foo.c#1,#3`

Again, doing this using an API will be much more efficient, as you can use a single connection for all the command calls.

Comment: I shoulda mentioned that I'm using P4Python and gave shell commands just for terseness.